# Can not connect to HBase using Execute script

Tags: groovy, hbase, apache-nifi, executeprocesstask

Get this error when trying to connect to HBase service.  I am just trying to implement increment HBase script but can not seem to figure out how to get already functioning HBase connection.

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.getConnection() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
on this code

```
import org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService
flowFile = session.get()

if(!flowFile) return

def lookup = context.controllerServiceLookup
def HbaseServiceName = HBaseConnectionName.value

def HBaseServiceId = lookup.getControllerServiceIdentifiers(ControllerService).find { 
    cs -> lookup.getControllerServiceName(cs) == HbaseServiceName
}
def conn = lookup.getControllerService(HBaseServiceId)?.getConnection()
```

Comment: Variable names shouldn't start with capital letters. I don't think this is the issue in this case, but can you try starting then with lower case letters, to remove one area of doubt?

Comment: nah not it the same error. Looks like getConnection is not exposed for nifi client.  I may need to write something of my own... :(

Comment: What should `lookup.getControllerService(HBaseServiceId)` return? What does it return?

Comment: Getting the controller service should return an instance of HBaseClientService, the interface is here https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-hbase-client-service-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/hbase/HBaseClientService.java

Comment: right @BryanBende but how do I now connect to HBase client using this. to run my increment :(

Comment: @andrewshved you can't get the underlying Hbase client, the point is that the controller service hides the real HBase API from the processors, so if someone implements a new HBaseClientService for a newer HBase client, the processors don't have to change